# Broken physics.sty after today's MiKTeX update, how to fix?

Tags: miktex, delimiters, physics

After the latest MiKTeX update, I started getting "Missing delimiter (. inserted)." errors on places where I've never had such before. A somewhat minimal .tex file points the problem to physics.sty. Here is it:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=40pt,right=40pt,top=45pt,bottom=40pt}

% Bibliography/References:
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % puts bibliography in ToC
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

% Language settings for special characters:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% enumeration and items:
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% page numbering:
\setenumerate{label={\normalfont(\arabic*)}}

% mathematical packages:
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % additional caligraphic font for math
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % for commutative diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,>=angle 60} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{exp}
        \exp(T)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{T^k}{k!}\in K[[T]]
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

```
physics.sty error line 34: Missing delimiter (. inserted). \exp(T)
physics.sty error line 34: Missing delimiter (. inserted). \exp(T)
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is the entire log: http://pastebin.com/S80vDD7J

Comment: Erh according to ctan, the physics package was last updated in 2012. When was the last time you updated miktex? Also it might be an idea to also post the entire log file

Comment: @daleif: hi and thanks for your reply. Actually, the last time I updated MiKTeX (aside from today) was roughly a month ago, so not that long ago :) Things still weren't broken. But I guess I should have known better. I will include the full log ASAP.

Comment: Also did you update both user and admin?

Comment: @daleif: I updated only as admin as I have the bad habit of logging as admin in windows... Now that I've checked again, the above seems to be the entire log in TeXstudio. Is there a "fuller" log? BTW, I've also made sure to synchronize the package manager, just in case that was the problem, but it wasn't.

Comment: Look for the file with the same name as your doc, but extension `.log`

Comment: Ah, right, found it. It's a lot of text, so I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/S80vDD7J I hope that's OK.

Comment: This is to do with some changes in `xparse` (used by `physics`): we are likely to update CTAN shortly to address them at present but I would urge you not to use `physics`: it is not really using `xparse` in the way intended.

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks for the info! Do you have any recommendations for a replacement? I am in the middle of a project with lots of partial derivatives and probably a bunch of other things that I don't even realize rely on the physics package. Though none of these seem to be included in the errors so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by some changes in `xparse`, used by `physics`. Essentailly, `physics` (and some other packages) have used 'document commands' in a way that the team did not expect (nor intend to support). We will be issuing an `xparse` update shortly to fix the issue *whilst we decide on a long-term policy*. Once that happens it's likely that the team will explicitly rule out certain use cases, at which point `physics` will need an update.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I hope I am not being indiscreet if I ask you whether there is a rough time table when this `xparse` update will be released?

Comment: @July Just working out a few details: CTAN probably tonight into TeX Live by Thursday and MiKTeX probably within a week,

Comment: Oh, that is much quicker than I expected to hear! Sounds great and thanks again! That settles it then, at least in the short term.